# Django inline edit of model with FilePathField

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this simple setup:

```
class Artist(Model):
  ...

class Download(Model):
  artist = ForeignKey(Artist)
  title = CharField()
  file = FilePathField(...)
```

and the admin looks like this:

```
class DownloadInline(TabularInline):
  model = Download

class ArtistAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [DownloadInline,]
```

I get a validation error for the `Download` inlines every time I try to save the `Artist` record. The Admin seems to think I'm trying to add new `Download`s to the `Artist`, even though I haven't filled in the `"title"` fields - the `FilePathField` gets preset to a filename by default and there's no way to set it to None.

Is there a way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is very likely a bug. Please simplify it to the smallest possible code sample that reproduces the problem (including all details, such as the arguments you're passing to FilePathField), and file it at http://code.djangoproject.com/.